# Why does this await return undefined?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
const checkBatchStatus = async (batchId: number) => {
let result = await fetchcall("POST", "api/batch/status", { "BatchId": batchId })
    .then(result => {     
        Promise.resolve(true);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        Promise.resolve(false);
    });
};
```

the caller code is the following:

```
async function isBatchRequestCompleted(batchId: number) {

    let status = await checkBatchStatus(batchId);
    console.log(`status is ${status}`);
```

status is always undefined.   Not understanding why.

If I change the checkBatchStatus to simply return false, then I get status equal to false.

```
const checkBatchStatus = async (batchId: number) => {
    return false;
};
```

Can a kind soul explain to me what I am seeing?

Comment: you're not returning anything from your `checkBatchStatus` function

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a single `return` statement. It needs three.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't return a value in the function `checkBatchStatus()`. And calling a  `Promise.resolve()` in callback function of `.then()` is a wrong idea if you want just a Boolean value.

```js
const checkBatchStatus = (batchId: number) => {
  return fetchcall("POST", "api/batch/status", { "BatchId": batchId })
    .then(result => {     
        return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return  false;
    });
};
```

Comment: This still won't work.  Nothing is returned from the `.then()` handler or the `.catch()` handler.  And, there's no reason for the `await` or even the `async` at all.

Comment: OK, got it now.  FYI, there's nothing technically wrong with using `return Promise.resolve(true)` in a `.then()` handler.  It's just not necessary when `return true;` will work just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 I assume that he doesn't expect a thenable object based on what he tried. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing both promises and async/await unnecessarily here. I suggest sticking with one or the other.

`async`/`await`:

```
const checkBatchStatus = async (batchId: number) => {
  try {
    await fetchcall("POST", "api/batch/status", { "BatchId": batchId });
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Or promises:

```
const checkBatchStatus = (batchId: number) => {
  return fetchcall("POST", "api/batch/status", { "BatchId": batchId })
    .then(result => true)
    .catch(err => false);
};
```